# writing a simple condition for pine script

Tags: function, conditional-statements, pine-script, indicator

I want to write a simple condition for pine script that if the price hits the plus sign the background color will be green like the following picture. but I wrote it and it wasn't what I expected it makes background only for two candles and I want it for all of the next candles. How can I do that? Thank you [This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYXWg.png)

```
//@version=4
study(title="My Indicator", overlay=true)
// Entry Point
entryPointLong = highest(high, 100)
entryPointShort = lowest(low, 100)
// Entry Point Condition
entryPointLongCond = close >= entryPointLong ? color.green : na
entryPointShortCond = close <= entryPointShort ? color.red : na
// Plot
plot(entryPointLong, title="Entry Long", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, show_last=1, color=color.green)
plot(entryPointShort, title="Entry Short", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, show_last=1, color=color.red)
// Background Color
bgcolor(entryPointLongCond, transp=70)
bgcolor(entryPointShortCond, transp=70)
```

Updated Code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="My Indicator", overlay=true)
// Entry Point
entryPointLong = highest(high, 100)
entryPointShort = lowest(low, 100)
// Stop Loss
stopLossLongInput = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) * 0.01
stopLossLong = entryPointLong * (1 - stopLossLongInput)
// Entry Point Condition
entryPointLongTrue = close >= entryPointLong
if entryPointLongTrue
    entryPointLong := stopLossLong
    color.green
entryPointLongCond = close >= entryPointLong ? color.green : na
entryPointShortCond = close <= entryPointShort ? color.red : na
// Plot
plot(entryPointLong, title="Entry Long", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, show_last=1, color=color.green)
plot(entryPointShort, title="Entry Short", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, show_last=1, color=color.red)
plot(stopLossLong, title="Entry Short", style=plot.style_cross, linewidth=5, show_last=1, color=color.red)
// Background Color
bgcolor(entryPointLongCond, transp=70)
bgcolor(entryPointShortCond, transp=70)
```

Comment: I'm writing an indicator for Trading View platform. The plus sign looks back for 200 candles of highest price. I want to write a condition that if the price hits the plus sign, background color will be green and then opens a long position but for now I only want my background color to be green.

Comment: The background color only makes two candles green but I'm trying to write a code that sets stop loss 3% below the entry point so that next candles will be green. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)

CO1 = "Crossover", CO2 = "Above"

priceLevel = input(1650)
condition  = input(CO1, options=[CO1, CO2])

var bool triggered = na

if condition == CO1
    triggered := crossover(close, priceLevel)
else if condition == CO2
    triggered := close > priceLevel
else
    triggered := false

bgcolor(triggered ? color.green : na)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help

Comment: This answer does exactly what you asked in your original question. But I see you changed it now. It's generally better to provide feedback as to what's wrong with it, instead of just saying it didn't help.

Comment: I appreciate that you wrote a code but this is not what I want. I updated my code and If you copy and paste it to your pine editor it works. but the problem is that it only makes background for one or two candles and I want to make background for the next candles unless it hits the stop loss which is 3 percent below entry point